# Wordpress showing article title, but content is showing blank

Tags: database, php-fpm, wordpress, php7

I recovered from a disaster situation on the server, database is not affected.

My wordpress files were old, from previous version (maybe 4.3). When I recovered those file and setup nginx with it, I see title, theme and everything, even the article titles after the backup time (because database is not affected), but not the content (not in home page nor in article page)

I updated to the latest 4.4 just now but it did not fix the titled problem.

When I try to edit the article, the content is in the editor. I click save and on the blog page, the content is still blank on that article.

I am also suspecting that this could be a php problem. I installed the latest php7 from Remi's RPM. It was previously php 5.6 (from remi as well)

What can I proceed to fix this? Thank you.

error.log, a lot of in wp-code-highlight plugin:
`PHP message: PHP Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in ....`

When I disable the plugin, the content is back.

Comment: Anything in the site `error_log`?

Comment: Switch back to the default theme (Twenty Sixteen) and see if the content reappears.

Comment: Message seems clear, the plugin is not compatible with PHP-7 (and dev have just ignored "deprecated" messages for... a long time)